# Cloning a div using a For-Loop isn't giving the right amount of clones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a script that will clone a div, cards in bootstrap 4, and change text in the div. I want this to happen a certain number of times., depending on the variable. However, when I use the script below I'm getting 8 cards (7 clones), instead of the 3 clones that it is supposed to be making. Does anyone know what is happening here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var cards = 3;
var id = ""; 
var newClass = ""; 
var i;

for(i = 0; i < cards; i++) {
    id = id + "1"; 
    newClass = newClass + "1"
    $(".listings").clone().addClass(newClass).appendTo("body"); 
    $("."+newClass).attr("id",id);
    $("#" + id + " " + "h1").text("$5000"); 
}

});
```

Comment: .clone() is work  1=2, 2=4, 3=8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
.addClass(newClass)
```

to

```
.prop("class",newClass)
```

Comment: It worked! Can you explain why this fixes it? ...or is it just one of those things